# Общение клиента и сервера по Tcp

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

Необходимо реализовать общение между клиентом и сервером, с помощью `TcpClient`.
Клиент отправляет на сервер запрос типа "дай мне такую то информацию", а потом ожидает ее от сервера. Сервер получает запрос, обрабатывает его и отправляет его клиенту.

**Вопрос** состоит в том, можно ли это реализовать с помощью одного `TcpClient` у каждой из сторон, и как это сделать? Или нужно делать два отдельных потока для отправки запроса и получения ответа?

Например, что будет, если запихнуть в один поток свой запрос и сразу же попытаться вытащить из него ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TcpClient` реализует **отправку и получение в синхронном блокирующем режиме** -- т.е. основной поток программы дожидается, пока операция не будет завершена.
Если *запихнуть... и сразу же попытаться вытащить* :) то получиться только после полного окончания :)) отправки/получения.
На MSDN есть описание класса `TcpClient` с [примером](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx), не вижу смысла его копипастить.
Если предположить, что вы хотите использовать это в он-лайн игре -- КМК, такой механизм может вызывать *подвисания*, если его применять для динамичного взаимодействия.